# How to count unique/ distinct visible values in a filtered column, with considering blank cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As such references I had found, those are not covering **"assuming blank cells same as non-blank ones"** matter.

I had found this array formula: (Ref: [extendoffice.com](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3255-excel-count-unique-values-in-filtered-column.html))

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(D2,ROW(D2:D22)-ROW(D2),,1)), IF(D2:D22<>"",MATCH("~"&D2:D22,D2:D22&"",0))),ROW(D2:D22)-ROW(D2)+1),1))`

Any guides are appreciated.

### Update

[image]

`F22` result of calculating for `Table1[Column1]`

`G22` result of calculating for `Table1[Column2]`

`H22` result of calculating for `Table1[Column3]`

**I want the Formula returns: `G22=4` & `H22=1`**

**Note:** My table has filtered range and I calculating visible values.

Comment: what do you mean "with considering blank cells"? Can you give an example? Does it stop calculating at the first blank cell in the range?

Comment: Means: 1) the column may contained **no blank cells**. 2) the column may contained few items blank cells. 3) the column may contains **all the cells are blank cells**. *I need in* case1: add 0 to the result of example referred formula in the original question; case2: add 1 to the result of example referred formula in the original question; case3: add 1 to the result of example referred formula in the original question. Regards.

Comment: Could you share some example data in an [edit] such as what you're formula *is* returning, and what you *need* to return?  (More info in: [mcve])

Comment: **Does it stop calculating at the first blank cell in the range?**: If reached the first blank cell, add 1 to the result and do continue calculating, (act with blank cells, same as another values cells.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the formula you quote the `SUBTOTAL` part is used to only consider visible cells.......but it also ignores blanks, so if you want to include blanks as another distinct value to be counted that's a problem.

Do you have any column that you know will be fully populated (e.g. column A)? If so you can base the `SUBTOTAL` part on that column and the counting distinct on the actual column in question, e.g. assuming `A2:A22` will always be fully populated try this version to count distinct values in `D2:D22` (including blanks):

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($A2,ROW($A2:$A22)-ROW($A2),,1)),MATCH("~"&D2:D22,D2:D22&"",0)),ROW(D2:D22)-ROW(D2)+1),1))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>